# Repair Ubuntu and Windows system loading from dualboot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, dualboot, suspend

I have some strange behavior with my ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 4th. It has two OS: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 I working only with Ubuntu, but I cannot delete Windows, because it is a work laptop.

Earlier I have some problems with suspend on Ubuntu - it doesn't loaded and I had to reboot it, because laptop doesn't load and has blank black screen.

I googled some solution to this problem and installed a screensaver. But after some time, after rebooting, my laptop won't load Ubuntu. But, Windows refused to load also.

I can work in ubuntu only in recovery mod and I tried to install a new kernel, but with new version ubuntu doesn't load at all.

How can I fix this problem, and what's the reason of this behavior?

Also, I think what it can be videodrivers, but i have internal videochip (intel) and Windows can't loaded too.

May be something wrong with GRUB?

Comment: The issue and the sequence of events as described seem totally disconnected. Installing a screensaver cannot mess with Grub let alone Windows. So, something else must have happened. Irrespective of that "something else" you should start by trying to boot Windows directly (UEFI > Boot) and if it boots make sure everything is fine (install pending updates, etc.) and disable Fast Startup, a must when dual-booting. Then change the boot order to Ubuntu and try booting.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot boot into Windows at all. All what I see - Win logo and after that it turns off

Comment: That being the case you need to prepare a Windows installation USB and use it to repair or, worst case scenario reinstall, Windows. You may need to do the same for Ubuntu. Those are independent repairs, of course. And before any it might be a good idea to check the health of the drive.

Comment: As I remembered, disk health is fine, I already checked it. But I'll check it again.